# Why can't I switch accounts after rebooting?

Tags: multi-user

I have a lenovo android tablet with three users - The Owner user, which is the original user and is an Admin.  Then two users for my children, which are restricted users.

The tablet seems to be 'stuck' logged into one of the children's account.  From the lock screen, I can access the switch user functionality, but the other users are greyed/disabled and nothing happens when I touch them.  Same thing if I go to settings -> System -> multiple users.

From what I can gather, the tablet was signed into the child's account then lost power and has been stuck in this state since it rebooted.

I found [this other question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221046/how-to-unlock-non-owner-account-after-reboot?newreg=278d141f99fc4ce98195fafef40c026f) but it seems to be the opposite of my problem - in that case, they cannot use the child accounts until they log in with the admin account.

The device is a Lenovo TB-7306F running Android 11.

Comment: Which of the tree accounts is the primary account? The primary/master account always needs to be logged in first after a reboot.

Comment: The owner account is the primary.  Problem is, I can't log in to that account, as the lock screen only allows the child account that last used it.

Comment: You can try to boot to safe mode.

How to boot to safe mode - 
Select the normal power-off/shut down menu and then click and hold the "power off/shut down" option for like 3-5 seconds and you will be given the option to log in to safe mode.

After you are logged into safe mode with your admin user account, reboot now to normal mode.

Let's see if the above exercise can be helpful.

Comment: By any change do you have USB debugging enabled or can you manage to enable it in safe mode?

Comment: Booting into safe mode did not allow me to change users.

Comment: I was also unable to enable USB debugging in either safe mode or normal mode.

Comment: By that I mean, I was unable to enabled the Developer options on this device.

Comment: I ended up doing a factory reset on the tablet just to make it usable by other people.

Comment: I have very same problem. @theycallmemorty How did you eventually solved the issue ? I mean in longterm ? Tablet with just one account ? No secondary account ?

Comment: @HoppusHoppard I'm sorry I never actually got this to work. I had to do a factory reset on the tablet and start from scratch.