# Lenovo P11 Plus - Only admin can log-in into table at first after restart

Tags: multi-user, lenovo

I got a P11 Plus (Android 11) for my son, and I am having troubles with a behaviour that is extremely frustrating.

- When setting up the tablet, I first set myself as the owner/admin (i.e., the first account to be set-up in the table was mine).
- Then I proceeded to set my kid's account (child under 13). I got kids space working, family link, etc.

What I noticed is that if the tablet is restarted, only my account can unlock the tablet.

- My kid's account (or any other account besides my own, the admin) is greyed out and cannot be selected at this point.
- If I unlock the tablet, then other users will be able to log-in with their accounts.
  This renders the tablet usless to my family unless I am around after a tablet reboot!

Now, had I made my son the first user in the tablet, he would have been the admin. The result is a ridiculous situation in which he would be able to log-in a temporary guest account and bypass all restrictions, EVEN IF I BLOCKED HIM FROM CREATING ACCOUNTS. Indeed he wouldn't be able to create accounts, but he would be able to mess around with the guest access all the same.

Anyway, I'd say it is perfectly reasonable to expect that a parent would be the first account (admin) of a tablet, before it is handed over to a child.

So how can I allow my kid to log-in into the tablet after a reboot?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know it is a built-in requirement of Android that after a reboot always the first/admin user has to log in. AFAIK this is because otherwise the necessary encryption keys are not available. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245732/2241 The only work-around I see is to let your child learn that the tablet should not be shut-down or rebooted. Instead set it to Flight-Mode to save battery.

Comment: @Robert Thanks. Maybe there is a work around in which I don't have a lock on my account, but there is a locked "shell" that restricts access to everything, including system settings?