# add guest and add users grayed out

Tags: settings, lock-screens, tablet, multi-user, lenovo

The **add user** and **add guest** buttons on the lock screen of my lenovo tab p11 are disabled after leaving my tablet for a week.

I have turned on the ability to add a guest and new user from the lock screen in the settings. This lets me add a guest or a user by clicking the button on the lock screen as you would expect. However, after leaving the tablet for a week the add user and add guest buttons are now greyed out and disabled.

The number of users has not been maxed out as no users have been created.

If I log in as the main user and then restart, the buttons are enabled again. but this is not an ideal solution for me.

edit:

my question has been answered here

[How to unlock non owner account after reboot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221046/how-to-unlock-non-owner-account-after-reboot)

Comment: It can help to know the reason for this requirement. Is this sitting in public space?

Comment: The tablets are booked out for short periods of time. using a guest account allows me to quickly wipe the account when they bring it back.

Comment: My question has been answered here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221046/how-to-unlock-non-owner-account-after-reboot Unfortunately after a reboot you seem to have to log in as the main user.